# Shiny: How to detect which accordion elements is selected?

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, shinyjs

I have an R Shiny where `server.R` outputs a large number of dynamically generated UI objects.

Rather than process hundreds of objects in `input` to process, I thought I could use [`bs_accordion()`](https://ijlyttle.github.io/bsplus/articles/overview.html#accordion) from the [bsplus](https://github.com/ijlyttle/bsplus/) package.

I expected `bs_accordion()` to report the state of the elements it controls back to `server.R` via the `input` object.

My plan had been to dynamically generate the UI elements for just the currently selected item using `renderUI()`.

Unfortunately as far as I can tell, nothing in the `bsplus` package puts anything into `input`.

The following works in the browser console (let's suppose the accordion element is `MYACCORDION`)...

```
MYACCORDION.onclick=function(){
Shiny.onInputChange('SELECTED_DIV',document.getElementsByClassName('in')[0].getElementsByClassName('shiny-input-container')[0].id
}
```

... `in` apparently is the class bs gives the element currently selected in the accordion and there is always just one. So after I do that, `input$SELECTED_DIV` gets updated whenever something new is selected.

But I cannot do the above programmatically. I tried putting it in `tags$script(...)` at the end of `fluidPage()`, and it does not get attached to the div. I also tried inserting it inline via `div(...,onclick=FOO)` but the value of `onclick` gets escaped and in the output and not interpreted as text.

- Where is the correct place to insert `onclick` functions in `ui.R`?
- Alternatively, how do I force the value of an `onclick` attribute to be treated as-is without escaping symbols?
- Or is there already a package for Shiny for attaching Javascript functions to `onclick` events?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest setting a dummy input that will hold the current value (or in this case, text) of the selected tab.

This might help you:

```
library(shiny)
library(bsplus)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    tags$script("$(function() {
                  $('#meet_the_beatles a').on('click', function(x) {
                    Shiny.onInputChange('selected_tab', x.target.innerText)
                  });
                });"),

    fluidRow(
      column(
        width = 6,
        offset = 3,
        bs_accordion(id = "meet_the_beatles") %>%
          bs_append(title = "John", content = "Rhythm guitar, vocals") %>%
          bs_append(title = "Paul", content = "Bass guitar, vocals") %>%
          bs_append(title = "George", content = "Lead guitar, vocals") %>%
          bs_append(title = "Ringo", content = "Drums, vocals")
      )
    ),

    HTML("<input id='selected_tab' type='text' style='display: none;'")
  ),

  server = function(input, output, session) {
    observe({
      print(paste("The selected tab is", input$selected_tab))
    })
  }
)
```

Comment: This looks like it may work! I'll try it ASAP and see what happens, thank you.

Comment: @Yanir. Thank you so much.  Two years later... your code just saved me.

Comment: I see accordian feature is also in shinydashboardplus package. Anyone has ideas of comparison between the bsplus and shinydashboardplus accordians?