# Shiny output plot based on input inside bs_accordion

Tags: r, shiny, accordion

I have a set of inputs inside bs_accordion and would like to output a plot based on the selected inputs and active/expanded panel, but I'm not sure how to link the selected input based on this active/expanded panel. Is there a way to know which panel is active? My code is below and thank you in advance.

```
library(shiny)
library(bsplus)
library(shinyjs)

month_data <- data.frame(Region = c(rep("Region M1", 20), rep("Region M2", 20)),
                         Value = runif(40))
day_data <- data.frame(Region = c(rep("Region D3", 20), rep("Region D4", 20)),
                       Value = runif(40))


m1 <- selectInput(inputId = "in_month_region", label = "Region", choices = c("Region M1", "Region M2"))
d1 <- selectInput(inputId = "in_day_region", label = "Region", choices = c("Region D3", "Region D4"))

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  useShinyjs(),
  
  actionButton(inputId = "toggle_menu", label = "Options"),
  
  br(),
  
  sidebarLayout(
    
    div(id = "Sidebar", 
        sidebarPanel(width = 3,
                     bs_accordion(id = "input_panel") %>%
                       bs_set_opts(panel_type = "success", use_heading_link = TRUE) %>%
                       bs_append(title = "Monthly", 
                                 content = m1) %>%
                       bs_append(title = "Daily", 
                                 content = d1))),
    
    mainPanel(plotOutput("myplot"))
    
  )
  
  
)




server <- function(input, output, session){
  
  observeEvent(input$toggle_menu, {
    shinyjs::toggle(id = "Sidebar")
  })
  
  get_data <- reactive({
    if(!input$in_month_region %in% c(NULL, "")){
      a <- subset(month_data, Region %in% input$in_month_region)
    } else if(!input$in_day_region %in% c(NULL, "")){
      a <- subset(day_dat, Region %in% input$in_day_region)
    }
    
    return(a)
    
    })
  
  
  
  output$myplot <- renderPlot({
    
    mydat <- get_data()
    
    plot(mydat$Value, main = unique(mydat$Region))
    
  })
  
}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53642157/shiny-how-to-detect-which-accordion-elements-is-selected) help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Shiny: How to detect which accordion elements is selected?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53642157/shiny-how-to-detect-which-accordion-elements-is-selected)

Comment: Thanks @Limey, it helps but with my limited java & html knowledge, I'm not sure how to change the function into plot instead of text.