# Can I use observeEvent() with bsplus::bs_accordion

Tags: r, shiny

Does anybody know if I can use an observeEvent() to watch for the click event on a fold of an accordion in bsplus::bs_accordion?

Here is what I mean....

I have a `bs_accordion()` control from the `bsplus` library in my shiny app.  Each "fold" of the accordion has content that is being dynamically set with a `uiOutput()` function:

```
      bs_accordion(id = "measures") %>%
        bs_set_opts(use_heading_link = TRUE) %>%
        bs_append(
          title = "Measures 1",
          content = uiOutput("measure1_ctrl")
        ) %>%
        bs_append(
          title = "Measures 2",
          content = uiOutput("measure2_ctrl")
        ) %>%
        bs_append(
          title = "Measures 3",
          content = uiOutput("measure3_ctrl")
        )
```

The content within each fold of the accordion (the `uiOuput()`) is created like this:

```
  output$measure1_ctrl <- renderUI({
    measure1 <- dashboard_master %>%
      filter(major_outcome == "1") %>%
      select(MeasureId) %>%
      deframe() %>%
      unique()
    radioButtons("measure1",
      label = NULL,
      choices = measure1
    )
  })
```

I can use an `observeEvent()` to watch for changes in the `radioButons` for "measure1" within the accordion code like this:

```
  observeEvent(input$measure1, {
    outcome_reactive$outcome <- input$measure1
  })
```

What I can't figure out is, can I use an `observeEvent()` to watch for the accordion to be selected/unfolded (before somebody clicks a radio button)?   I figure there is a click event happening but I don't know what it is called.  So, I don't know how to put it into an `observeEvent()`.

Comment: As far as I can see, the accordion is controlled in javaScript, so there may not be a shiny event corresponding to what you want.  [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53642157/shiny-how-to-detect-which-accordion-elements-is-selected) describes how to identify *which* fold of an accordion is active, so presumably it could be modified to report if no fold is active as well.  That would give you what you want.

Comment: Thank you so much Limey.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you need to use some `JS` to solve this. Here's a minimal example:

```r
library(bsplus)
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
   tags$script(HTML("$(function() {$('.panel').on('click', function() {Shiny.setInputValue('alert', this.id);})})")),
   fluidRow(
      bs_accordion(id = "measures") %>%
         bs_set_opts(use_heading_link = TRUE) %>%
         bs_append(
           title = "Measures 1",
           content = uiOutput("measure1_ctrl")
         ) %>%
         bs_append(
           title = "Measures 2",
           content = uiOutput("measure2_ctrl")
         ) %>%
         bs_append(
           title = "Measures 3",
           content = uiOutput("measure3_ctrl")
         ),
       verbatimTextOutput("dbg")
   )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
   output$dbg <- renderPrint(input$alert)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Basically, you assign a `click` event to the `panel` class, which tells `shiny` (via `input$alert`) that something is clicked.

You may want to add a random number in `setInputValue` in case you want to catch consecutive calls. In my toy example I returned the `id` of the panel, which was clicked, but of course you can return whatever you want (and Javascript/jQuery lets you).

Comment: Thank you @thothal. I am very grateful for the help!